# Property 'jsonData' not found on object of type 'MapViewController *'

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode4.3, arcgis

I am trying to draw the route on the graphic layer of my app application and i do not know is this the right approach to do it, or is there another way to do it? Where i am trying to use NSArray with ArgGIS to draw out the map am i have problem with it.

*edit I tried to change the NSArray back to a JSON string and try to draw it using ArcGIS with a JSON string

This is what i have done:

```
NSArray *BusRoute=[jsonResult objectForKey:@"BusRoute"];
int i;
int count = [BusRoute count];
for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
{   
    NSDictionary *dic = [BusRoute objectAtIndex: i];
    NSString *Duration = [dic valueForKey:@"Duration"];
    //---PATH---
    NSArray *PATH = [dic valueForKey:@"PATH"]; 
    NSLog(@"PATH = %@", PATH);
    self.path = PATH;
}
NSError *writeError = nil; 
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:path options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&writeError];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 
    NSLog(@"JSON Output: %@", jsonString);
if (self.jsonString) {
        // symbolize the returned route graphic
        self.jsonString.routeGraphic.symbol = [self routeSymbol]; 
        
        // add the route graphic to the graphic's layer
        [self._graphicsLayer addGraphic:self.jsonString.routeGraphic];
        
        // tell the graphics layer to redraw
        [self._graphicsLayer dataChanged];
    }
```

*Output for JSON string

```
JSON Output: [
  [
     "38909,35576;38872,35589;38861,35593;38848,35597;38697,35650;38695,35651;38695,35651;38609,35681;38583,35689;38553,35697;38508,35700;38476...;29560,40043"
  ]
]
```

---

This is a portion of the path that i have to draw on the map:

```
PATH = ((  "38909,35576;38872,35589;38861,35593;38848,35597;38697,35650;38695,35651;38695,35651;38609,35681;38583,35689;38553,35697;38508,35700;38476,35696;38476,35696;....))
```

for this line `self.jsonData.routeGraphic.symbol = [self routeSymbol];` i am getting an error `Property 'Property 'jsonData' not found on object of type 'MapViewController *'`

what should i do to solve? pls help

---

*How can i draw the line of the path using the `NSArray` and using ArcGIS?

Comment: Is there a way where i can draw the path on the graphic layer using the `NSArray` with `ArcGIS`?

Answer (score 0):

`routeGraphic` property does not have any association with NSArray Class. NSArray is the Collection.

Your code is a little strange.

what is `routeGrphic`???

Are not you forgotten the like code below?

```
YourObject *object = [path objectAtIndex:index];
object.routeGraphic.symbol = [self routeSymbol];
```

Comment: `YourObject *object = [path objectAtIndex:index];` this is in the for loop which is `NSArray *PATH = [dic valueForKey:@"PATH"]; ` and i pass it out to `path`.

routeGraphic is use from the ArcGIS bundle